# Why does the baseline memory usage keep increasing when switching between empty Activities?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, garbage-collection

I was recently playing around with the profiler to find out how memory usage react when switching between activities to get a better understanding of how memory usage in Android Studio works.
I read a lot about memory leaks, what causes them and how to prevent them.
However, I encountered behavior which I have not (yet) found a satisfying explanation on.

I have two empty Activities (they both only have one button in the middle to move from one Activity to the other). I do NOT store any variables (more specifically views) in the Activity classes. When switching between activities I properly start the other activity and finish the current Activity, so memory *should* be released.

However, using the profiler, I found that when switching a bunch of times between activities, the baseline memory would still increase. As an example, the baseline memory usage starts out at around 66mb. When switching a bunch of times (somewhere like 20 to 30 times) and making sure that the memory has stabilised (whilst also forcing garbage collection), the memory usage stays at around 73.2mb.

Here are my two activity classes in question:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class));
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class));
            MainActivity2.this.finish();
        });
    }
}
```

[Here is the memory log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TalFp.png). Notice the spikes are the periods where I was switching a lot between activities, and then notice that the baseline memory (in particular the baseline Native memory) keeps increasing.

An explanation of this behavior would be greatly appreciated!